# Limit the Products for Particular Category?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list

I have a "New Arrival" Category. I need to show the Latest product of the top level category ( Mens->New arrival) and limit the products. 
I have tried to override the below category block. But not achieve that.

File Path : `\\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Category.php`

```
if($this->getId()==463){ // New arrival Category ID
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(18);   // Mens category ID            
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
        ->addCategoryFilter($category)->setPageSize(1,10);
}else{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
        ->addCategoryFilter($this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
$_categoryId = 18;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryId );
$productCollection = $category->getProductCollection();
$productCollection
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addUrlRewrite();

$productCollection->getSelect()->limit(20);
```

Comment: I already tried above code, but return all products for that category. Its not assigned the product collection.

Comment: @Rat , try updated code above

Comment: its not working.  while printing the $collection get the 20 produts for above code. But not assigned the productcollection of actual magento

Comment: @Rat , i updated code. try please. Also flat category is enabled in your site?

Comment: Raiput ,  Flat category is disabled.  I tried the above code, its loading long time

Comment: @Rat Ok try above. It not taking more time to load

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76363/discussion-between-chirag-rajput-and-rat).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit Your code**

```
->setPageSize(1,10);
```

**to**

```
->setPageSize(10);
```